# How to programmatically create a folder using c#

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, development

I have a Pages folder and inside the Pages folder, I have a Class folder in my SharePoint .

So I should create a folder inside that class folder!

Comment: Dear,  Is it SharePoint Online !!! if No, Please remove it from tags .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code to create a Folder (including nested) via CSOM in SharePoint 2010/2013,

```
/// <summary>
/// Create Folder client object
/// </summary>
/// <param name="web"></param>
/// <param name="listTitle"></param>
/// <param name="fullFolderUrl"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Folder CreateFolder(Web web, string listTitle, string fullFolderUrl)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullFolderUrl))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("fullFolderUrl");
    var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
    return CreateFolderInternal(web, list.RootFolder, fullFolderUrl);
}

private static Folder CreateFolderInternal(Web web, Folder parentFolder, string fullFolderUrl)
{
    var folderUrls = fullFolderUrl.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string folderUrl = folderUrls[0];
    var curFolder = parentFolder.Folders.Add(folderUrl);
    web.Context.Load(curFolder);
    web.Context.ExecuteQuery();

    if (folderUrls.Length > 1)
    {
        var subFolderUrl = string.Join("/", folderUrls, 1, folderUrls.Length - 1);
        return CreateFolderInternal(web, curFolder, subFolderUrl);
    }
    return curFolder;
}
```

To use it

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext("https://contoso.onmicrosoft.com/"))
 {
       ctx.Credentials = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials("username", "password");
       var folder = CreateFolder(ctx.Web, "Shared Documents", "FolderA/SubFolderA/SubSubFolderA");
 }
```

[Ref : How to create Folder (including nested) via CSOM in SharePoint 2010/2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001237/creating-folders-programmatically-in-sharepoint-2013)

Check Simlier thread [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8bd508f5-50dc-443b-84fd-e375ec32d1ce/create-folder-in-document-library-using-sharepoint-2010-client-object-model?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

Also check C# Server Object model [programmatically-create-folder-in-sharepoint-list](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/programmatically-create-folder-in-sharepoint-list/)

Comment: Worked!!! Thank you!